# Gerar relatório em segundo plano em php

Tags: php, codeigniter, mpdf

No sistema que estou desenvolvendo chegou na parte mais critica que é a geração de relatórios. Desejo gerar um relatório que quando for solicitado pelo cliente, ele informar uma mensagem dizendo que assim que o relatório estiver pronto será encaminhado um e-mail informando.

Eu já tenho o relatório pronto, porém são muitos dados e acaba demorando para ser gerado.

Eu uso o CodeIgniter e para gerar o PDF o mPDF.

Preciso de sugestões para fazer dessa forma ou até mesmo como criar um serviço que rode em segundo plano no PHP para gera o relatório

Comment: Acredito que você esteja interessado em concorrência, certo? Se for, dê uma pesquisa em Threads com php: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.thread.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem algumas formas de realizar o que você necessita, uma delas bem simples e a outra necessitaria de interação com o shell.

**AJAX**

A primeira e a mais simples de todas,  Faça a requisição do script via AJAX. Sendo ele assíncrono, você não precisa esperar a resposta e não irá travar a execução (por parte do browser).

Alguns cuidados são necessários nesse caso. É necessário fechar a `session` para que, em uma futura requisição, o servidor não esteja ocupado por uma `session` aberta. Para isso, utilize [`session_write_close`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php).

**[exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) e/ou [shell_exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)**

Você pode utilizar o próprio sistema operacional para executar ou agendar a execução do script. Entretanto, vale destacar que o acesso direto ao `shell` é perigoso e deve ser evitado (ou usado com muito cuidado).

Um pouco mais de informações, você pode obter aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4628279/1628790

**Threads**

PHP possui suporte a `threads` e, nesse caso, você poderia utilizar uma `thread` sem esperar a resposta dela. Vale ressaltar que nesse caso eu estou "teorizando", pois, nunca utilizei na prática uma `thread` sem esperar a resposta (nem sei se é possível). Mas fica mais uma possível solução.

[PHP: pthreads](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php)

**Considerações**

Indiferente a escolha, o seu script terá sua execução iniciada e, logo em seguida, será avisado ao usuário que o resultado será enviado por e-mail (sem que o script tenha sido executado por completo).

De todas as soluções, eu escolheria a primeira. Fácil, rápida e funcionará sem problemas e com poucas alterações no seu código.

**UPDATE**

Foi questionado, nos comentários, se o usuário fechando o browser não iria interromper a execução do script no PHP.

Nesse caso, é importante entender como o PHP trata uma requisição:

1. Requisição realizada (nesse caso, o browser);
2. Requisição recebida (pelo servidor);
3. Execução do script;
4. Output/saída;
5. Término da execução.

Outro detalhe, é que os passos 3 e 4 podem ser intercalados. O PHP não precisa executar todo o script para realizar o output. O output pode ser realizado durante a execução de um script.

Quando o output é realizado, o PHP verificará se existe uma conexão ativa esperando uma resposta. Nesse momento, entra uma diretiva chamada [`ignore_user_abort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/misc.configuration.php#ini.ignore-user-abort). O padrão default dela é `false`.

Basicamente, essa diretiva define que, se uma conexão não estiver ativa, a execução do script será interrompida. Ou seja, se não houver o browser (ou qualquer outro tipo de cliente) esperando a requisição, a execução do script será interrompida.

Entretanto, o PHP só tem ciência de que a conexão não existe, quando tentar realizar o primeiro output.

[**PHP: ignore_user_abort - Notes**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php#refsect1-function.ignore-user-abort-notes)

> **PHP will not detect that the user has aborted the connection until an attempt is made to send information to the client**. Simply using an echo statement does not guarantee that information is sent, see flush().

Nesse caso, o seu script executará até que seja enviada alguma informação para o cliente. Como no seu caso, nenhuma informação será enviada para o cliente, você não precisará se preocupar com isso.

Se isso fosse uma necessidade, bastaria alterar a diretiva para `true` ou utilizar a função [`ignore_user_abort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php)

Comment: Usando AJAX daria para eu fazer da seguinte forma: O cliente solicita o relatório ai em seguida mostra a mensagem que será encaminhada um e-mail quando estiver pronto e ele poderá sair do navegador (fechar) e mesmo assim ele irá receber o e-mail? Ou com alguma das que falou daria para fazer?

Comment: @Weslley entenda que, uma vez a requisição enviada para o servidor, não existe modo de interrompê-la pelo browser. O servidor receberá a requsição, executará ela, e fara o output (resposta). A única diferença que não terá um browser esperando pela resposta do servidor (o que não é necessário no seu caso).

Comment: Entendi Gabriel, até testei e deu certo. O que devo fazer agora é otimizar o relatório para evitar timeout. No caso, na parte servidor poderia usar Thread para fazer o processamento da requisição?

Comment: @Weslley fiz uma atualização na resposta sobre um fato interessante (mas não se aplica ao seu caso). Você pode usar thread sim, mas o simples fato de usar thread não melhorará a performance do seu script. É mais interessante verificar algo é a demora de execução e atuar em cima dos gargalos.

Comment: Obrigado Gabriel, sua resposta me ajudou muito!

Answer (score -1):

eu tenho a mesma situação de execução de um script php para alguns relatórios sintéticos, muito pesados em formato .xlsx, onde a demora de resposta no navegador é totalmente fora do aceitável para o operador, então faço da mesma forma que o @Weslley de enviar o relatório por email aos interessados. Como solucionei a questão do timeout: no loop de tratamento dos dados, tenho algumas condicionais em alguns pontos estratégicos que verificam o tempo de execução, ao ultrapassar o tempo, exemplo 30 segundos, o script executa um refresh em si mesmo, lembrando que antes foram guardadas variáveis de sessão para assegurar que o script retome a execução e continue de onde parou. Observação: caso o operador (cliente) opte por extrair a mesma informação em formato .csv normalmente não ocorre o timeout. Saudações.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).